# flask_restx fields.Raw does not allow None

Tags: python, json-schema-validator, flask-restplus, flask-restx

I just switched from flaks_restplus to flask_restx. I start getting the marshal error.

```
jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: None is not of type 'object'
```

I defined this field in my modal, and the dict I passed in.

`"my_field": fields.Raw`

`{... 'my_field': None}`

How can I allow None for the field?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the answer.
The field I defined is wrapped in `field.Nested()`

I have to pass in the optional parameter `field.Nested(myModel, skip_none=True)`

It is not intuitive...